# How to call drawer navigator inside function in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, navigation-drawer, drawer

I am new to React-native. So I don't know much about navigation. When I click my image I need to open my drawer side menu.
I called my drawer inside the function.

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function TopBar(props) {

    function sideMenuHandler() {
        return (
            <NavigationContainer>
                <Drawer.Navigator>
                    <Drawer.Screen name="SideBar" component={SideBar} />
                </Drawer.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>

        );
    }

    return (
        <>
            <View>
                    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={sideMenuHandler}>
                        <Image source={require('../assets/profile.jpg')} onPress{sideMenuHandler}/>
                    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>

 
                </View>
            </View>

        </>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to describe your Drawer at the Root of your application as desribed in the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-based-navigation).

Answering your question opening, toggling or closing a Drawer pane programmically you can use [DrawerActions](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-actions) or the shortcut described below.

Import useNavigation to access navigation props.

```js
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/core';
```

Apply Actions by dispatching them:

```js
const navigation = useNavigation();

const handlePress = () => {
    navigation.toggleDrawer();
}
```